# Dynamically change template based on user type

Tags: parameter, dynamic, page-content

We're about to move to Magento 2.3.
Trying to understand whether a product page can display one of two actions based on the visitor/customer type.

I have one product with two different customer types.

The product information is the same for both but the action I want them to take is different.

- B2C customers should be asked to buy the product.
- B2B customers should be asked to fill in a form to speak to a rep.

If the customer is unknown then we ask to self-select their customer type, otherwise we direct them to areas of the website that is relevant to them.

If the customer is B2B then instead of price and Buy Now button they are presented with a button to Speak To A Rep.

I'm not looking for a technical response - just some advice.

I was told this was only possible via an extension that is going to cost more than we can afford at the moment. Is this true?

Seems like it should be configurable natively.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, the question is whether this is only possible via an extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it by customer groups.

If you are using Magento EE, It will provide you B2B feature. It will enable you to set permission based on various customer groups.

Only a few customizations require to do this.

Comment: Thanks @91Devendra Kushwah. So, does that mean the page template or a content block can change if the visitor is identified as part of a customer group? Can this be done via URL Parameter - if the visitor visits B2B pages before they get to the product page can they be assigned to the B2B customer group?